# Progressive Draw 2 and Draw 4 Uno

Tags: house-rules, uno

When playing with progressive `Draw 2` and `Draw 4` and (say that there are 2 players playing) and

1. Player 1 goes out with a `Draw 2`
2. Player 2 puts down a `Draw 2`

Does player 1 have to pick up 4 cards?

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the base rules of the game it ends as soon as a player has no cards in their hand. Which means that the second player would not have a chance to play the draw 2 in response to the first players card.

Also should be noted that if you are playing in a situation where you want to continue playing till everyone but the last person runs out of cards it would be the same. As soon as a player plays their last card they would be out of the game and not impacted by any cards.

[uno rules](http://www.unorules.com/)

> Scoring: When a player no longer has any cards and the game ends, he/she receives points. All opponents’ cards are given to the winner and points are counted. All number cards are the same value as the number on the card (e.g. a 9 is 9 points). “Draw Two" – 20 Points, “Reverse" – 20 Points, “Skip" – 20 Points, “Wild" – 50 Points, and “Wild Draw Four" – 50 Points. The first player to attain 500 points wins the game.

Answer (score -3):

I think its right answer for game 1st player have to pick up 4 cards because second player is also challenging again.than it will be more interesting.

Comment: This answer is being downvoted because a) it's difficult to read (not well formatted or in good grammatical English) and b) it appears to be completely your own opinion with no reference to any written rules.